# Error on new server: PDO not found (supposed to be activated)

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, whm

I just configured a cPanel server and transferred all my websites to it. Everything works fine except for a Symfony2 website. Here's the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/cosml/public_html/vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php on line 32
```

I use PDO in the other websites, so I don't understand. I checked in phpinfo; no PDO section. I tried to rebuild Apache in WHM with PDO activated but with no difference. I really don't know what's going on,

Comment: enable it in php.ini by remove `;` before PDO extension

Comment: You may need to install PDO library explicitly. Try to install using SSH Also you may need to install Mysql_pdo as well. BTW which linux flavour you are using? AND Yes check php.ini setting as well.

Comment: I checked the php.ini, it is enabled too... How can i install it using SSH ?

Comment: see this http://karoshiethos.com/2008/07/24/installing-pdo_mysql-on-centos/ page

Comment: Thanks but i already tried this too...

Comment: are you sure install down correctly without error?

Comment: maybe `php-cli` using a different `php.ini`  check the `php.ini` path from `phpinfo()`

Answer (score 2):

To enable PDO in the system PHP:

1. Login to WHM
2. Click Apache Update
3. Click Start Customizing Based on Profile
4. Select an Apache version
5. Click Next Step
6. Select PHP 5
7. Click Next Step
8. Select a version of PHP 5
9. Click Next Step
10. Click Exhaustive Options List button
11. Scroll down to the check box labeled PDO
12. Click Save and Build

Source : http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/enable-pdo-78853.html

Also, did you restart apache after enablind PDO ?

Comment: Did that 3 times... PDO is already checked, but it won't work :/ And Easyapache rebuild apache so it is restarted ...